# Report Of Work Items & Their Parents

Tags: azure-devops

Hey Folks my org recently migrated from TFS 2017 to VSTS online. Our IT Finance team  has a report that show work items along with their parents and your grandparents. It was built around a SQL query that looked at the backend SQL database. Is there a way to create a report of all work items and their parents in VSTS online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to show all the work items as parent/child relation in VSTS. Detail steps as below:

1. Create a new query with Tree of work items type.

   [image]
2. Add the filter `Work Item Type` = `[Any]` both for top level work items and linked work items. And select `Parent/Child` Type of tree, then save the query.

   [image]
3. Run the query and you will get all the work items with tree view relations.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Marina. I tried this and got exactly what I needed. Good question and good answer.